How can I use a PR Template from a Submodule in GitHub?
Repo A: Contains a PR template at .github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md.
Repo B: Uses Repo A as a submodule.
Repo A (submodule in Repo B):
repo_a/
├── .github/
│   └── PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
└── ... (other files and directories)

Repo B:
repo_b/
├── repo_a/  (submodule)
└── ... (other files and directories)

Problem:
When creating a pull request in Repo B, the PR template from Repo A (submodule) is not being used automatically.
Question:
Is there a way to configure GitHub to use the PR template from a submodule? If not, what's the best practice for sharing a PR template across repositories when one is a submodule of the other? I do not want to use a universal template for all repos and would like to avoid using GitHub Actions if possible.
What I've Tried: The PR template works fine for Repo A. The template is correctly located in the submodule within Repo B. Adding ?template=pull_request_template.md to the PR creation URL doesn't work.

Regarding the GitHub documentation, it is only possible to create several templates in the PR templates folder.
There is also another nice summary from another user.

Thanks for the response, but I'm not trying to create multiple templates for pull requests on GitHub. I want to use the same template for multiple repos.

Okay but nevertheless the template must be in the .github folder. :D

You can use a symbolic link.
In the the repo_b, execute this command:

Linux:
ln -s ./repo_a/.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md ./.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md


Windows:
mklink .\.github\PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md .\repo_a\.github\PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md



This will create a symbolic link ./.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md pointing to ./repo_a/.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md. So, it will directly points to its content.
I tried it and it works fine with Git & GitHub.
Just don't forget to commit the addition of the symbolic link and then push.
Edit:
It don't work when we're making a pull request from another branch than  where the symbolic link was commited.

I created the symlink on my main branch of repo_b but rather then seeing the template markdown when I make a PR, I only see the path to repo_a/.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md.

You're on which platform? I tested on Windows and it worked, but I didn't test on Linux.

I tried several variations of this, but am not having any success with the symlink approach. Whenever I make a new PR on a branch other than main (where the symlink lives) I only see the symlink path text, not the PR template markdown.
For this particular use case, I'm using Windows 10 Pro. I set my git config values to true to use symlinks.

Ok. I'll continue my tests and tell you the advancements.

I tried everything on Windows, and it don't seem to work. I tried normal symbolic link, a hard link, nothing worked. Sorry. I'll try on Linux, in case of.

It don't work on Linux too. Really sorry. The problem is from GitHub, not from my answer.
